# Can I have a curly brace as macro argument delimiter?

Tags: macros, delimiters

Is there any trick that allows to have a `{` in argument delimiters of a macro ? 
for example, with this definition :

```
\def\start#1\fin{+++#1+++}
```

the call

```
\start coucou\fin{3}4
```

will display

> +++coucou+++34

because `\fin` is the right delimiter of the argument of the macro `\start`. Now, i would like the whole `\fin{3}` to be the delimiter. So that the same call as above would now output:

> +++coucou+++4

The problem is how to include the curly brace in the delimiters.

**Edit1** In particular, I would like the following call

```
\start coucou\fin{2}blabla\fin{3}
```

to "output"

> coucou\fin{2}blabla

but, regarding to David's comments, it seems to be impossible.

Comment: It's impossible to have what you ask in the title, however it is of course possible to define a command that works as in your edit. Just define it as in my or egreg's version but of the argument after `\fin` _isn't 3 then just recurse and collect up to the next `\fin` and check again. This is how environments like tabularx or ams alignments that collect environments work, they scan up to `\end` check if it is the correct environment and if not collect up to the next `\end`. Oh I just realised `\fin` is probably `\end` if you're not english:-)

Comment: can you make this in an expandable way ? I would appreciate a few lines of code.

Comment: ok, i guess i could try to learn it in tabularx...

Comment: well, it seems to me, that the idea you wrote in your comment above is precisely egreg's solution. Is it something more ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I hadn't looked in detail at egreg's. I could delete my comment if you think it confusing or leave it, as it's true:-)

Comment: "can you make this in an expandable way " yes egreg's is expandable

Comment: no. nothing confusing now. Thanks for all the answers. :) And yes, `\fin` sounds like `\end`, you are right ! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the arguments to `\fin` are simple numbers, you can check whether the argument is `3`; here's a Plain TeX version (put the standard things to make it into LaTeX).

```
\def\start{+++\startaux}
\def\startaux#1\fin#2{%
  #1%
  \ifnum#2=3
    +++%
  \else
    \fin{#2}%
    \expandafter\startaux
  \fi
}
\def\fin#1{-#1-}

\start cocou\fin{3}

\start cocou\fin{2}blabla\fin{3}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I think this is the answer I need :)  By the way, what is `\bye` supposed to do ? for my TeX, it is just an undefined control sequence...

Comment: @nicolasroy `\bye` is the Plain TeX way to end a job.

Comment: thank you for this wonderful solution! Could you briefly explain how the recursive part `\expandafter\startaux` works?

Comment: @ValenStein `\expandafter` will expand `\fi` (leaving nothing); this finishes up the conditional and `\startaux` will examine the next token.

Answer (score 3):

No you can have `\lbrace` a command token that acts like `{` in some contexts and you can have a character token `{` of a different catcode such as 12 (other) but a token list (however constructed) can not have mis matched token of catcode 1 or 2.

---

So best you can do is something like:

```
\def\start#1\fin#2{%
\ifnum3=#2 +++#1+++\fi}
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the output that you want.  I'm not sure that it will resolve whatever issue it is that led you to ask the question though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\start#1\fin{+++#1+++\fin}
\def\fin#1{}
\begin{document}
\start fish\fin{3}4
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, it gives the output I mentioned... but does not solve the problem of my EDIT1.