# Is it possible to use $ as a macro delimiter?

Tags: macros, tex-core, delimiters

Experimenting with macro definitions that use strange delimiters (see e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36325/macro-delimiter) or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61608/can-i-have-a-curly-brace-as-macro-argument-delimiter?rq=1)), I thought it would be fun to have a macro that takes an argument of the form "a/b" and turns this into a fraction.

This is achieved by

```
\def\myfrac#1/#2 {\frac{#1}{#2}}
```

which scans everything before the slash into `#1` and everything following the slash until next space into `#2`. Hence,

```
$\myfrac 72/31 $
$\myfrac 7/13 34\times\pi$
```

produce

[image: compiled code]

as desired. But -- unsurprisingly --

```
$\myfrac 72/31$
```

gives a `**! Missing } inserted.**` error, as -- of course -- the delimiting space is missing. To circumvent this, I wanted to define

```
\def\myfrac#1${\@myfrac#1 }
\def\@myfrac#1/#2 {\frac{#1}{#2}}
```

i.e. scan everything up to the next `$`, add a space to the end and then pass it to the other macro. This, however, results in `! Missing $ inserted.`

Note, however, that it works with a "normal" delimiter:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\def\myfrac#1x{\@myfrac#1 }
\def\@myfrac#1/#2 {\frac{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\myfrac 72/31x$ $\myfrac 3/15 x$
$\myfrac 7/13 34\times\pi x$
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: compiled output]

as expected. So is there a way to replace `x` in the above code with `$`?

Comment: This is because the `<argument>` text gobbles everything, including the `$`, which is never replaced. Use `\def\myfrac#1${\@myfrac#1 $}`.

Comment: By the way, `siunitx` offers with the option `quotient-mode=fraction` the same: `\num[quotient-mode=fraction]{72/31}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this is just for experimenting, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\myfrac#1${\@myfrac#1 $}
\def\@myfrac#1/#2 #3${\frac{#1}{#2}#3$}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\myfrac 72/31$ $\myfrac 3/15$ $\myfrac 7/13 34\times\pi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The “parameter text” is removed from the input stream and substituted with the replacement text, so the closing `$` must be reinserted at the end.

The `$` in the replacement text of `\myfrac` and in the parameter text of `\@myfrac` can be any token that's not expected to be in the formula, so also `\@nil` could be used; but using `$` is just as safe.

Don't use delimited arguments in LaTeX at the user level.

Answer (score 3):

Your actual problem is that you are falling afoul of the issue discussed (ironically, this week) in [Is \def sensitive to spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127665/is-def-sensitive-to-spacing/127666#127666).  Don't put a space after `#2` and you will be fine.  The reason your second workaround works is that you insert the space explicitly in `\@myfrac`.  The reason your first workaround *doesn't* work is that you remove the `$` as part of macro expansion (it's absorbed as part of the arguments) but don't put it back, so TeX is quite right that it's missing.

Comment: Well the space is there to act as "second delimiter" so that something like `\myfrac 7/13` is set as `\frac{7}{13}` and not `\frac{7}{1}3`. The point of the "exercise" was to use two alternative delimiters (either a space or a `$`), so the space is desired.

Comment: Perhaps you want a second delimiter that you don't implicitly consider to be discardable text, then.  This will free you from having to gobble to the end of the math group, too.